# single spa won't display two apps at the same time

Tags: angular, single-page-application, single-spa-angular, single-spa

I have set up an environment using single spa and I am experiencing strange behavior. I have three angular apps set up: a navbar app, with two pages of its own, app1 and app2, with several pages to be displayed under the navbar. I was using this repository as a model: https://github.com/joeldenning/coexisting-angular-microfrontends . I understand the repository was changed three days ago, I am using the previous commits as a model.

behavior:
localhost:port/ - shows navbar - correct

localhost:port/navbarPage - shows navbar and navbar page - correct

localhost:port/app1Page - displays only the navbar for several seconds and then switches to showing only 
the app1Page or vice versa - wrong

What is really strange is that both single spa template divs are displayed and app1Page is inside the navbar div and the app1 div contains an empty app-root element. (see below)

[example of error...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F7Sj.png)

I Noticed you updated the index html to use single-spa-layout, but I am still using the old version FYI. Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src *  data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; font-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline';"
    />

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <title>Your application</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <meta name="importmap-type" content="systemjs-importmap" />

    <!-- "Landing-App": "http://localhost:4203/landing", -->

    <script type="systemjs-importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "App1-App": "http://localhost:4201/main.js",

          "App2-App": "http://localhost:4202/main.js",

          "Navbar-App": "http://localhost:4300/main.js",

          "single-spa": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/single-spa/5.5.0/system/single-spa.min.js"
        }
      }
    </script>

    <link
      rel="preload"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/single-spa/5.5.0/system/single-spa.min.js"
      as="script"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.1.4/minified.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/import-map-overrides@1.15.1/dist/import-map-overrides.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/system.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/amd.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-exports.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/4.0.0/extras/named-register.min.js</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>

      System.import("single-spa").then(function (singleSpa) {
        singleSpa.registerApplication(

          "Navbar-App",
          function () {
            return System.import("Navbar-App");
          },

          function (location) {
            return true;
          }
        );

        singleSpa.registerApplication(
          "App1-App",

          function () {
            return System.import("App1-App");
          },

          function (location) {
            return location.pathname.startsWith("/app1");
          }
        );

        singleSpa.registerApplication(
          "App2-App",

          function () {
            return System.import("App2-App");
          },

          function (location) {
            return location.pathname.startsWith("/app2");
          }
        );

        singleSpa.start();
      });
    </script>
    <import-map-overrides-full></import-map-overrides-full>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was my app root selectors/html tags were the same across all three apps and were confusing single spa when it brought them all together. I changed them to unique selectors and it worked! (ie. `<app-root></app-root>` to `<app-name-root></app-name-root>`)